# Intel nvidia OpenGL driver difference mod-function

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have the problem that my fragment shader gets executed very differently on my intel graphics chip then on the nvidia chip. (Both drivers are up to date)

The problem seems to be the mod-call in the following code:

```
float opRep( vec3 p, vec3 c ){
  // gl_FragColor = vec4(max(0.0, sign(p.x)), max(sign(p.y), 0.0), max(sign(p.z), 0.0), 1);
  vec3 q = mod(p,c)-0.5*c;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(max(0.0, sign(q.x)), max(sign(q.y), 0.0), max(sign(q.z), 0.0), 1);
  return twistedColumn( q );
}

float distanceFromPoint(vec3 point) {
  return opRep(point, vec3(90.5, 0, 98));
}
```

The gl_FragColor are my "debug" statements. The debug statements print the sign of the points because I think the mod function returns different signs on the diffrenet drivers.

If I uncomment the first debug output I get the same visual results. But after the mod, the visual result varies between the intel graphics driver and the nvidia version which is very confusing.

Can someone give me a hint why I get different results... ?

Comment: Anything in the GLSL compilation and link logs with Intel?

Comment: None with intel, following by nvidia:

Vertex info
-----------
0(2) : warning C7555: 'attribute' is deprecated, use 'in/out' instead
0(3) : warning C7555: 'varying' is deprecated, use 'in/out' instead

Fragment info
-------------
0(267) : warning C7533: global variable gl_FragColor is deprecated after version 120

so no...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call your mod function with a 0-argument. The intel driver and nvidia will produce diffrent results

Answer (score 2):

`mod` is a discontinous step function -- a very small change in `p` can result in the `mod` flipping between `0` and `c`.  As a result, any use of `mod` is very sensitive to rounding details, which may vary between GL implementations.  OpenGL does not prescribe any particular rounding method for interpolation or any other operation that may give a result that cannot be precisely represented in the implementation's internal numeric representation.  It only prescribes minimum precision requirements for calculations -- any implementation is free to use more precision if it wishes.

So what is probably going on is that one of the chips uses more precision than the other for some calculation, or one is rounding down while the other rounds to nearest, or some other variation or combination of effects.

Comment: If I change the 0 in the caller 

    return opRep(point, vec3(90.5, 0, 98));

to 

    return opRep(point, vec3(90.5, 0.0001, 98));

I get the correct result on both chips. If I pass a 0, the sign of y component is treated differently on intel. You can produce this with: 

    vec3 modResult = mod(p, c);

    gl_FragColor = vec4(max(0.0, sign(modResult.x)), max(sign(modResult.y), 0.0), max(sign(modResult.z), 0.0), 1);

The upper half of the image is on the intel chip white, which means the sign of y is positive but not on the nvidia chip, there it is all magenta???

Answer (score 2):

```
vec4(max(0.0, sign(q.x)), max(sign(q.y), 0.0), max(sign(q.z), 0.0), 1);
...
vec3(90.5, 0, 98)
```

Watch those integer constants.  GLSL doesn't do automatic type promotion.  Try this:

```
vec4(max(0.0, sign(q.x)), max(sign(q.y), 0.0), max(sign(q.z), 0.0), 1.0);
...
vec3(90.5, 0.0, 98.0)
```

I'm surprised the Intel GLSL compiler let type errors like that slide with nary a warning.

Also, make sure all your shaders start with appropriate `#version` directives.